# Titanium, change TextField height with animation

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

In Appcelerator Titanium (iOS project) I have a `TextField` with `height:50`. The `TextField` contains much more text but the fact that its height is set to 50 lets me use the `TextField` as a preview of the remaining text: under the `TextField` I have a button and when I tap this button I want to show the entire text, so I would like to animate the `TextField` from its current height to `Ti.UI.SIZE`. Is this possible? How? I noticed some iOS properties (eg. anchorPoint) but I could not understand if they can be useful in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `TextArea` instead of `TextField` if you want multiple lines and word wrapping.

I've added the `TextArea` to a `View` so I can animate it to both expand and shrink it.

You can try something like this..

```
// Create the text area for multiple lines and word wrapping.
var messageField = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    color: 'black',
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE, // Set here the height to SIZE and the view's height to the required one, ex. 50
    textAlign: 'left',
    value: 'This text should be displayed in more than one line in a text area, but that behavior is not supported by a text field, again, This text should be displayed in more than one line in a text area, but that behavior is not supported by a text field.',
    verticalAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT_TOP,
    width: '90%',
    font: { fontSize: 20 }
});

// Add the text area to a view to be able to animate it
var view = Titanium.UI.createView({
    height: 50, // Required height
    top: 250,
    width: '90%',
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 2,
});
view.add(messageField);

// Create animation object
var animation = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
animation.duration = 1000; // Set the time of animation, 1000 --> 1 second

var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: "Show More",
    font: { fontSize: 18 },
    width: 100,
    top: 200
});
var isExpanded = false;
button.addEventListener('click', function() { // Event listener for your button
    if(isExpanded) {
        isExpanded = false;
        animation.height = 50; // Set the animation height to 50 to shrink the view
        view.animate(animation); // Start animating the view to the required height
        button.title = "Show More";
    } else {
        isExpanded = true;
        animation.height = Ti.UI.SIZE; // Set the animation height to SIZE to make it expand
        view.animate(animation); // Start animating the view to the required height
        button.title = "Show Less";
    }
});

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'white'
});

win.add(button);
win.add(view);
win.open();
```

Comment: This is ok, but I want an animation, not changing the height that way   :-)

Comment: @3000 I've added animation code, please try and let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: this is interesting but it causes another issue: I get the end of the text, not the beginning, so there's no "preview" effect

Comment: I think the only way to achieve such behavior will be by setting `scrollable` property of the `TextArea` to false, but the user will not be able to see all of the text until he clicks on Show More button.

Comment: Zabady, curiously your example is not working for me, BUT I used the same code (it's fairly identical) loading my text in the textarea and it works (don't ask me why, I don't know)   :-)

Comment: This happens a lot in Titanium :D, I wish they fix such things in the next SDK.